# Incompatible curl with git clone

Tags: python, git, anaconda

I made an empty project on GitHub and I am trying to clone it locally to upload code, however when I do it fails with

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: git-remote-https requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 11.0.0
```

Looking at 'which curl' return only my anaconda curl. Looking at my anaconda revisions it does not look like I upgraded core/git at any time.
I am running MacOS 10.15.7 and I installed git directly from https://git-scm.com/downloads.

The command used was just

```
git clone https://github.com/myusername/mypackage.git
```

EDIT:

I installed now git through homebrew but there is the same error

Comment: What operating system are you on? How did you install git?

Comment: And what is the exact command that raised the error?

Comment: @Marcel see edit

Comment: I'm assuming *"OS"* is *"MacOS"*?

Comment: you're going to need a more recent set of system libs, look up mac os homebrew.

Comment: You should install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and then run `brew install git` to make sure you also get all the right versions of all dependencies. It should find you a version of git that's compatible with your system.

Comment: cannot install homebrew due to the same error